# React error :: TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, select, typeerror, event-listener, imagesource

I was trying to implement an telephone picker with a according to the following

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './component_style/telinput.css';
export class telinput extends Component {
    render() {
         const selectCountryChange = ({target}) => {
        const img = document.querySelector('#img');
        const select = document.querySelector('#country');
        const tel = document.getElementById('tel');

        let prevVal = select.value; 

        if(tel.value) tel.value = `${select.value}${tel.value}`;
        else tel.placeholder = `${select.value}${tel.placeholder}`;


        const reg = new RegExp(`(^${prevVal} )`);
        if (reg.test(target.value)) tel.value = tel.value.replace(reg, target.value);
        else tel.value = `${select.value}${target.value}`;




        if(tel.value) tel.value = `${target.value}${tel.value.replace(reg, '')}`;
        else tel.placeholder =  tel.placeholder.replace(reg, target.value);
        prevVal = target.value;


        img.src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`


    }

        return (
            <div>
                <div className="tel-input">
                    <div className="tel-mechanism">
                        <div className="select-box">
                            <img
                                src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/MeRahulAhire/country-calling-code-html/master/phone_icon.png"
                                alt=""
                                id="img"
                            />
                           <select id="country">
                              <option data-countryCode="IN" value="91">India</option>
                              <option data-countryCode="US" value="1">US</option>
                              <option data-countryCode="GB" value="44">UK</option>
                           </select>
</div>
                        <div className="input-box">
                            <input type="tel" placeholder=" 956 826 4457" alt="" id="tel" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default telinput;
```

but i got this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
selectCountryChange
C:/Users/Rahul/Desktop/collegefacemash/src/form/components/telinput.js:20
  17 |      else tel.placeholder = tel.placeholder.replace(reg, target.value);
  18 |      prevVal = target.value;
  19 | 
> 20 |      img.src = `https://flagpedia.net/data/flags/h80/${this.selectedOptions[0].dataset.countrycode.toLowerCase()}.webp`;
     | ^  21 |  };
  22 | 
  23 |  return (
```

I really didn't understand that why such error occurred in react whereas when the `selectedOptions[0]` is the native JavaScript property and should work well.

can anyone tell me what should I do to correct this
Thanks...

Comment: The `this` keyword refers to your React component instance and it doesn't have any such property.

Comment: I could not see `selectedOptions` anywhere else other then where you are accessing? how are you assigning value to `selectedOptions`?

Comment: I was trying to convert an phone picker which i made into `html` and `js` into `React`  [See this for more info](https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/fus7xv/whats_the_proper_way_of_selecting_selectedoption/). The demo is also available [here](https://telinput.netlify.com)